# Merging master to squashed develop

Tags: git, github, repository

I have followed situation.

Short brief:
I have `master` branch and `develop` branch. On `develop` I have squashed commits from feature branches (when I merge feature branch to `develop` via GitHub I select **Squash and Merge** option. But when I prepare a release and I do something like that:

```
git checkout develop
git checkout -b rc-2.0.0
git push origin rc-2.0.0
```

I create a PR to master and merge it **without squashing**.

The problem:
After that, I "incidentally" added more changes directly to `rc-2.0.0` and merged them into `master`. Now when I am trying to merge `master` to `develop` I get a lot of changed files in GitHub even when the files are identical. `git diff` command between `master` and `develop` shows me one changed file. How to fix that? I want to have only this one change displayed during merge request master to develop

Comment: Some of this is confusing. To clarify: before you added one more change, you had 3 branches: `rc-2.0.0` which was the same as `develop`, and both were (I assume) ahead of `master` with nothing new on `master`. Then you added one commit to `rc-2.0.0`, but I don't understand what you mean by: pushed that to `master`. Maybe `master` is not locked down to require a PR into it and you accidentally updated `master` to look exactly like `rc-2.0.0`? Is that what happened? Are they on the same commit, or, did this happen after your already merged `rc-2.0.0` into `master`?

Comment: Also, just so you can rule this out, try doing `git fetch` and then diff `origin/master` and `origin/develop` to make sure you're doing the same diff that GitHub is doing.

Comment: @TTT My rc was equal to develop. I merged rc to master. Then, I added something to rc and merged again to master (but not to develop) as hotfix. THen I made some hotfixes again and merged them to master. Now I want to align develop and master because develop is behind master and moreover develop has its own changes merged. Now, when I create a branch from develop and merge master to it, I have a lot of changes even in equal files

Comment: OK. Got it. I made some wording changes to your question to capture what you said in the comment. So I think this reduces to: `develop` and `master` are equal. There were hotfix commits that are now in `master`, and other commits were added to `develop`. When I merge `master` back into `develop` I see more files as changed in GitHub than actually are changed. Why? (Does that summarize the issue?) Now, is GitHub showing files as changed but when you click on them there are no differences? If yes, is it possible the changes are whitespace or line endings only?

Comment: @TTT it may be something with that commits to develop are squashed but commits from develop to master are not?

Comment: That should only matter if the same commits are going into two branches and one side is squashed and the other is not. For example, if you merge `rc` into `master` without squash, and then also merge `rc` into `develop` with squash, then you'd have duplicate commit IDs with the same information. Functionally it wouldn't matter when you merge merge `master` back into `develop`- the code would be the same but there would be duplicate IDs which could cause confusion later on. But, when you merge `master` back into `develop` you aren't squashing right? (I don't think you should.)

Comment: No, because I did not merge `master` to `develop` because of issues. Here you have an image of how it looks right now. I want to have changes from master in develop (5 files changed across this all commits) changed https://imgur.com/JT04jHH

Comment: @TTT funny, probably some servers in your region are down but they should somehow redirect traffic I think. Here you have in other hosting. https://postimg.cc/jnnCGhg1 I will be grateful for help

Comment: I don't see anything out of the ordinary in the image. I guess I'm still confused by "I have a lot of changes even in equal files." If there's a change, then the files aren't equal- right? Do you mean in the list of files that are changed, some files are showing up that when you look at them there aren't actually any changes?

Comment: @TTT the problem is that when I do pull request `merge` master to develop in Github I see 5 files changed (and it is ok) but when I do `rebase` I see twice more (10) files changed. In both cases I also see ~50 commits (but master is ahead as you can see on image of less than 10 commits)

Comment: Usually you don't want to rebase master or develop, because you want to preserve all the merge commits they have. In the image I can  see 18 commits on master that aren't on develop, and there are others you can't see in the image. Note that all the merge commits will be counted too, even if they don't have any "changes" of their own.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is to do a `git rebase -i <sha before the branches diverged>` this will allow you to remove the merge commit and the log will be one single line as you wanted. You can also delete any commits that you do not want any more.

Comment: its not this case